# Vite Plugin: Understanding NodeJS and Export Default

Tags: node.js, vue.js, vite

I am building a plugin for [Vite](https://vitejs.dev/), to be used within a [Vue](https://v3.vuejs.org/) application.

I'll note that I'm running the following package versions:

- **Node**: `v14.15.3`
- **Vue**: `v3.0.11`
- **Vite**: `v2.1.5` (along with the Vue plugin *@vitejs/plugin-vue* `v1.2.1`)

My simple vite plugin, based on the [examples documentation](https://vitejs.dev/guide/api-plugin.html#simple-examples):

```js
/* my-plugin.js */

export default function myPlugin() {

  const hello = (name) => {
    console.log(`Hello ${name}`)
  }

  return {
    name: 'myPlugin',
    buildStart() {
      hello('World')
    },
    handleHotUpdate() {
      hello('World')
    }
  }

}
```

If I create my plugin file within the root of my project, everything works as expected:

```
my-app
 ┣ node_modules
 ┣ src
 ┣ my-plugin.js     <------
 ┣ vite.config.js
```

```js
/* vite.config.js */

import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'
import myPlugin from './my-plugin'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    vue(),
    myPlugin(),
  ]
})
```

If I attempt to introduce my plugin as part of a node package:

```
my-app
 ┣ node_modules
 ┃ ┣ my-package
 ┃ ┃ ┗ my-plugin.js    <------
 ┣ src
 ┣ vite.config.js
```

```js
/* vite.config.js */

import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'
import myPlugin from 'my-package/my-plugin'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    vue(),
    myPlugin(),
  ]
})
```

I get an error telling me that I have an unexpected token 'export':

```sh
failed to load config from C:\my-app\vite.config.js
error when starting dev server:
C:\my-app\node_modules\my-package\my-plugin.js:1
export default function myPlugin() {
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'
```

What am I not understanding here, and how do I make this work?

Comment: Have you tried using `.mjs` extension instead of `.js` ?

Comment: Yes. I get another error: `Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: Must use import to load ES Module: C:\my-app\node_modules\my-package\my-plugin.mjs` From what I've read, this typically indicates I'm running an older Node version. But in my case, I'm using Node `14.15.3`, so I wouldn't expect to see this error.

Comment: I believe that the error could mean that something tries to `require` your plugin instead of `import` it.